# Retrieving data from table recursively or by iterations - as a pedigree tree

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, algorithm

I'm having a problem with retrieving information from a MySQL Table with PHP.
I Have the following table in the MySQL database: 
id | pigeon_sn | mother_sn | father_sn 
id - represents the unique ID;
pigeon_sn - represents the pigeon ring serial number 
mother_sn - represents the mother of the pigeon - ring serial number 
father_sn - represents the father of the pigeon - ring serial number 
I'd like to retrieve from the database the information as a pedigree like file. 
This means I need to retrieve the information as follows: 
I insert the serial number of the ring of a pigeon. 
 - it gives me the serial number of the mother and father ring. 
 - then, for each new serial number ( mother and father ) retrieves the father corresponding to the serial no obtained before, and the mother corresponding to the serial no before.
 - the algorithm goes on for a given number of iterations ( For example 3 will retrieve 3 generations of pigeons by their mother and father serial number ).

I belive that this can be done recursively or just by an for algorithm that goes for a given number of iterations. For every pigeon ( pigeon is represented by the serial number obtained from the pigeon before ) the algorithm will create an associative array with all the information on that row table.

Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this working up if somebody needs it: 
 First you get the first pigeon and their parents:
 
 $pedigree[0] = $this->fetchRow("pigeon_sn='{$sn}'"); 
                $pedigree[1][] = $this->fetchRow("pigeon_sn='{$pedigree[0]['SN_m']}'");
                $pedigree[1][] = $this->fetchRow("pigeon_sn='{$pedigree[0]['SN_t']}'");
 and after that you will go like this:

```
    public function recurseDB($last_level,&$result,$level=1,$limit=2){
        //Check if las level was an array
        if($level <= $limit){
            if(is_array($last_level)){   
                foreach($last_level as $array){
                    $result[$level+1][] = $this->fetchRow("pigeon_SN='{$array['SN_m']}'");
                    $result[$level+1][] = $this->fetchRow("pigeon_SN='{$array['SN_t']}'");
                }
                $this->recurseDB($result[$level+1],$result,$level+1,$limit);
            }
            else
            {
                $result[$level][] = $this->fetchRow("pigeon_SN='{$last_level['SN_m']}'");
                $result[$level][] = $this->fetchRow("pigeon_SN='{$last_level['SN_t']}'");
            }
        }
    }
```

for the recursive funciton.

Answer (score 0):

Two things. You need both a method of tracking the parent-child relationship (while you have the parent's sn's, the logic to lookup and reference the id's gets convoluted fast when relating field-to-field lookups to id numbers to produce a result in which you need to repeat the process iteratively and recursively) in the same field, and a method of building the query logic so it runs a minimum number of times on the db.

So, first thing I would consider doing is either creating a lookup table (pigeon_id, mother_id, father_id) and creating a `LEFT JOIN` on the id values, or add two fields to the db (mother_id and father_id) and creating an alias for the table on which you `JOIN` the values on the id lookup, iteratively, when you build the query.